# PHP url rewrites not working (maybe due to Apache rewrites)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am developing a php website and am trying to get rid of the .html extension from the URL. Right now I am on the staging server.

Here is how the server is setup by a remote IT team:

- The server is called `int-dev.mydomain.com`.
- The URL for the website is `staging.mydomain.com/dev/home.html`.

When the server receives a request for `staging.mydomain.com/dev/` it basically forwards it to `dev.mydomain.com`; this is done through Apache. Per my understanding, `staging.mydomain.com/dev/` is not the same domain as `staging.mydomain.com`, but more like a vanity URL.

Now, I added a `.htaccess` file with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

It is not working when I try to access the URL without .html extension.

Any ideas/suggestions what could be the problem and what can I do about it?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have access to your vhost and apache2 config? Can you post this?

Comment: Are you sure your htaccess file is even being evaluated?

Comment: @Leon is home.html an existent file or it is home.php? Also what is your folder structure, for example: `/home/youraccount/public_html/int-dev/`, `/home/youraccount/public_html/staging/` or your sub domains all point to the same folder?

Answer (score 0):

Im using this with PHP and it's working fine for me

```
RewriteRule ^about$ about.php [L]
```

Try it like this

```
RewriteRule ^page_name$ page_name.html [L]
```

With this you have to specify all pages with your script